# Drupal 8 - Simple fb connect doesn't send "Welcome mail"

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-8

I'm using the **simple fb connect** module to create and login my users.

It's also possible to register with the build in registration from Drupal itself. Normally when a user registers, the Drupal system sends an account **"Welcome email**". 
But when users register via **Facebook**, it **doesn't send** a "Welcome email".

I've tried with the module **Rules** to send a e-mail after a User has been created with Simple Fb Connect. Then I have 2 options, to "**send an email**" or to "**send an account e-mail**". I have no idea how to fill in the required fields in neither options. If it's even possible yet, because it's still in development..

Does anyone know how to fill one of the two actions in Rules? Or know how I can send an e-mail programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with writing a custom hook_mail in the module "Simple fb connect" right after a new user has been created.